# Change text file coordinates to UK grid coordinate

Tags: python, grid, coordinates

I have a text file with lat/long which I would like to convert it to UK map grid base coordinates.

in the text file each line is like this:

51.505046,-0.12687

51.505046,-0.12687

51.508369,-0.120969

51.508369,-0.120969

51.508369,-0.120969

51.508646,-0.195893

51.508646,-0.195893

51.507841,-0.127332

51.507841,-0.127332

and I would like to change these values to:

530100,180120

530100,180120

530500,180500

530500,180500

530500,180500

525300,180400

525300,180400

530060,180430

530060,180430

I have written the following code, but get an error which cannot convert the coordinates. Do you have any idea?

> > > from OSGridConverter import latlong2grid
> > >
> > > filepath = 'C:/Users/Desktop/coo1.txt'
> > >
> > > file= open(filepath)
> > >
> > > for line in file:
> > >
> > > ...fields=line.split(",")
> > >
> > > ...field1=fields[0]
> > >
> > > ...field2=fields[1]
> > >
> > > ...g=latlong2grid (field1, field2)
> > >
> > > ...print(g.E, g.N)

Err: OSGridConverter.base.OSGridError: OSGridConverter error: Cannot parse argument 51.505046

I could convert each line separately by:

> > > g=latlong2grid(52.657977,1.716038)
> > >
> > > (g.E,g.N)

but not for a whole text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are passing a string to your function, convert it to float:

```
g=latlong2grid (float(field1), float(field2))
```